# Propagating touches from UIApplication in a custom manner

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touch, uiapplication, propagation

Is it possible to propagate touches from shared application object to a custom view which has not actually received touches and somewhere at the back of the top view? Assume that I can't use my top view to track touches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be difficult - because the top view receives the event first.

You can't just call userInterActionEnabled on the top view, and pass the event down to a lower layer?

Comment: no, because top view is a framework view which handles some complex touches on its own. I tried putting an overlay view and passing the touch events to this framework view but it didn't function properly. I also tried hitTest to track and pass touches down in the same way but no result again. The only remaining solution seems to be UIApplication. I think sendAction method must be doing something but I don't know where to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not use the top view to track touches?

If the top view is a subclass then you can use the touchesBegan: method.  To pass this onto another subclass you could just use NSNotificationCenter, passing the set of touches as the object.  If you're unfamiliar with this you can check out my explanation on this post:

[Hittest event problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538988/hittest-event-problem/1771376#1771376)