# Hittest event problem

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iPhone which contains  a series of views with webview .These views are placed in a scroll view .Now my problem is that i need to scroll the scroll view horizontally to move to the next view ,also i need to scroll the webview vertically to view its contents .I used "hittest" event of webview to capture the touch event and route the event appropriately .Now i need to fire the hittest event from touchesmoved function of the view after finding the direction of move(move webview scroll bar vertically if user touched vertically or show the next view if user touched horizontally) .I searched a lot for a solution ..Looking for a solution please help..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but if you are looking to communicate between classes you can use NSNotificationCenter.  This way the two views can communicate when certain events happen.

If you are unfamiliar with NSNotificationCenter I'll explain it briefly.

In both classes you would set up observers, usually in your initialisation method, like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:nil object:nil];
```

So in the classes where you have done this, you will need a method to handle the notifications. Here I've called it:

```
handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {}
```

Then, each time you want to communicate a message, just post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"aName" object:nil];
```

As you can see you can give the message a name and pass an object, which can be retrieved at the other end in your handleNotification method by using

```
NSString *name = (NSString *)[notifcation name];
id object = [notification object];
```